# Nativescript, Icon in text field

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Im trying to get Icons inside a textfield in a Nativescript Angular project. When I try to get this done it gets positioned outside the field, or at least it looks that way. I have looked at some code samples([sample](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-make-input-field-with-icon-on-the-left-in-ui/4335/2)) but it wont work when i try it myself.

```html
<GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" class="container" loaded="onLoaded()">
  <app-eon-colors-top></app-eon-colors-top>
  <StackLayout row="1" class="logo">
    <Image src="res://live_logo"></Image>
  </StackLayout>
  <Stacklayout row="2" class="form">
    <StackLayout>
      <TextField #userName hint="Användarnamn" class="field" [text]="userInput.username" required [isEnabled]="!(processing$ | async)" keyboardType="email" autocapitalizationType="none" autocorrect="false" (textChange)="setUsername($event)" (focus)="focusUserName($event)"
        (returnPress)="focusPassword()"></TextField>
    </StackLayout>
    <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto">
      <Label col="0" class="icon fa-regular" [text]="lockIcon"></Label>
      <TextField col="1" #password hint="Lösenord" class="field" [text]="userInput.password" required [isEnabled]="!(processing$ | async)" secure="true" autocapitalizationType="none" autocorrect="false" (textChange)="setPassword($event)" (focus)="focusPassword($event)"
        (returnPress)="submit()">
      </TextField>
      <Label col="2" class="icon fa-regular" [text]="activePasswordShowHideIcon" ios:style="padding-bottom: 35" (tap)="showHidePassword()"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
    <Label class="error-msg" textWrap="true" *ngIf="(errors$ | async)" [text]="errorTxt"></Label>
    <Button class="login-button" text="LOGGA IN" [isEnabled]="!(processing$ | async)" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
  </Stacklayout>
  <ActivityIndicator rowSpan="5" color="#23a1b0" [busy]="(processing$ | async)" width="100" height="100" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to remove the default background / border comes with TextField and apply the border to the parent container to make it look like it's part of TextField.

**Example**

```
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <GridLayout class="m-10 input-border" columns="*,auto">
            <TextField col="0" class="input"></TextField>
            <Label col="1" class="h3" text="" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=y7Bspr&v=1)

Comment: It will be helpful if you could elaborate what was your issue with Playground. Simply complaining the link doesn't work may not help. I'm sure the link is still alive, but functionality may be broken, you know the framework / playground changes here and then with updates. So just explain what is your issue please.

Comment: Updated the link with version key, without that it takes you to latest version thats modified by someone else which does not have the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting margin-right of the TextField to a negative value.  Not sure whether that's the right way.  But it appears how i wanted.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <TextField text="Test"
        (tap)="onCollectionDateTap($event)"
        style="width: 200; margin-right:-15;"></TextField>
    <Label class="fa" text="&#xf06e;" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```